# NodeJS - expressJS - req.body only get one variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a login and signUp pages, the login page get all variables right while the signup only transfer the password for some reason.

**App.JS:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// configure the app to use bodyParser()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true,}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = process.env.PORT || 5555;
const usersSignup = [];
const { Client } = require("pg");

//Create static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.post("/sign-in", function (req, res) {
  let email = req.body.email;
  let pass = req.body.psw;


  index = usersSignup.findIndex((x) => x.user === email && x.pass === pass);
  if (index != -1) {
    if (email == "Admin@g.com" && pass == "Admin") {
      res.redirect("/contact");
    }
    res.send(
      `Welcome!` + JSON.stringify(email) + "Password:" + JSON.stringify(pass)
    );
    console.log("Hello");
  } else {
    res.send("User not found");
    console.log("User not found");
  }
});

app.post("/sign-up", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var Fname = req.body.firstName;
  var Lname = req.body.lastName;
  var pass = req.body.Password;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var pCode = req.body.promoCode;

  con.query("select * from users where email=$1", [email], (err, res) => {
    var result = JSON.stringify(res.rows[1]);
    if (result != null) {
      console.log("User exists");
    } else {
      con.query(
        "INSERT INTO users (Name,FamilyName,Email,PromoCode,Password) values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)",
        [Fname, Lname, email, pass, pCode]
      );
    }
  });
```

**SignUp form** - req.body only get the password (psw) and nothing else... i tried to disable the modal but same problem.
the associated function are to check that both password are the same and to check password limits (6 digits,capital, etc...)

```
       <form method="POST" action="sign-up">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="firstName"
                                        placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="lastName"
                                        placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email"
                                    placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                    <input type="password" onclick="validFunc()" class="form-control" id="Password"
                                        name="psw" placeholder="Password" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="RePassword"
                                        placeholder="Repeat Password">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="test" class="form-control form-control-user" id="promoCode"
                                    placeholder="Promo Code">
                            </div><br>
                            <button type="button" onclick="displayForm()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#ModalMessage">Sign Up</button>
                            <div class="signUp"><br>
                                <hr>

                                <p><b>Already have an account? <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a></b></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                aria-labelledby="ModalMessageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalMessageLabel">Check details</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body" id="MBody">
                                            Please review the details and confirm:
                                            <p id="message"></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                onclick="sendMail()">Confirm</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Modal -->
                        </form>
```

**Login form (Works fine)** - all the data comes like it should.

```
              <form method="POST" action="sign-in">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><img
                                            src="/style/outline_account_box_black_18dp.png" alt=""></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><img
                                            src="/style/outline_lock_black_18dp.png" alt=""></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" onclick="validFunc()" class="form-control" id="Password"
                                    name="psw" placeholder="Password" title=" Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter and one special
                    char, and at least 6 or more characters" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeryQAaAAAAACtRGmnGbDekQjszQXzXrH858eJe"></div><br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return alerts()">Log In</button>
                            <div class="sign-up"><br>
                                <hr>
                                <p><b>Need an account? <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a></b></p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `name` attributes

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="firstName"
                                        placeholder="First Name">
```

Should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="firstName" name="firstName"
                                        placeholder="First Name">
```

HTML forms use `name` for sending data, not `id`

Do this for all inputs, also you wrote `name="psw"` on HTML but doing `req.body.Password` on server part, you need to correct this too.

Fixed HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="sign-up">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="firstName" name="firstName"
                placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="lastName" name="lastName"
                placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email"
            placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="password" onclick="validFunc()" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password"
                placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="RePassword"
                placeholder="Repeat Password">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="test" class="form-control form-control-user" id="promoCode" name="promoCode"
            placeholder="Promo Code">
        </div><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="displayForm()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#ModalMessage">Sign Up</button>
        <div class="signUp"><br>
            <hr>

            <p><b>Already have an account? <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a></b></p>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="ModalMessageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalMessageLabel">Check details</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="MBody">
                        Please review the details and confirm:
                        <p id="message"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                        onclick="sendMail()">Confirm</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Modal -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!!
cant believe I didn't noticed that (massive facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set name attribute for signup!

```
<form method="POST" action="sign-up">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="firstName" name="firstName"
                                        placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="lastName" name="lastName"
                                        placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email"
                                    placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                    <input type="password" onclick="validFunc()" class="form-control" id="Password"
                                        name="psw" placeholder="Password" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="RePassword" name="RePassword"
                                        placeholder="Repeat Password">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="test" class="form-control form-control-user" id="promoCode" name="promoCode"
                                    placeholder="Promo Code">
                            </div><br>
                            <button type="button" onclick="displayForm()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#ModalMessage">Sign Up</button>
                            <div class="signUp"><br>
                                <hr>

                                <p><b>Already have an account? <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a></b></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                aria-labelledby="ModalMessageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalMessageLabel">Check details</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body" id="MBody">
                                            Please review the details and confirm:
                                            <p id="message"></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                onclick="sendMail()">Confirm</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Modal -->
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the content of `validFunc()` that you used for `onClick` of password, and also the content of `displayForm()` used on form submit? I suspect that the missing fields somehow got `undefined` with your content checking code.